# Convert specific string to a numeric value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do data analysis of some rainfall data. Example of the data looks like this:-

```
10   18/05/2016   26.9     40    20.8     34   52.2    20.8   46.5     45   
11   19/05/2016   25.5     32     0.3   41.6     42     0.3   56.3   65.2   
12   20/05/2016    8.5     29    18.4      9     36    18.4   28.6     46   
13   21/05/2016   24.5     18   TRACE    3.5     17   TRACE    4.4     40   
14   22/05/2016    0.6     18       0    6.5     14       0    8.6     20   
15   23/05/2016    3.5      9     0.6    4.3     14     0.6      7     15   
16   24/05/2016    3.6     25       T      3     12       T   14.9      9   
17   25/05/2016     25     21     2.2   25.6     50     2.2     25      9
```

The rainfall data contain a specific string '**TRACE**' or '**T**' (both meaning non measurable rainfall amount). For analysis, I would like to convert this strings in to '1.0' (float). My desired data should look like this so as to plot the values as line diagram:-

```
10   18/05/2016   26.9     40    20.8     34   52.2    20.8   46.5     45   
11   19/05/2016   25.5     32     0.3   41.6     42     0.3   56.3   65.2   
12   20/05/2016    8.5     29    18.4      9     36    18.4   28.6     46   
13   21/05/2016   24.5     18     1.0    3.5     17     1.0    4.4     40   
14   22/05/2016    0.6     18       0    6.5     14       0    8.6     20   
15   23/05/2016    3.5      9     0.6    4.3     14     0.6      7     15   
16   24/05/2016    3.6     25     1.0      3     12     1.0   14.9      9   
17   25/05/2016     25     21     2.2   25.6     50     2.2     25      9
```

Can some one point me to right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), and then converting the numeric to `float` using `df.astype` (the original datatype would be `object`, so any operations on these columns would still suffer from performance issues):

```
df = df.replace('^T(RACE)?$', 1.0, regex=True)
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].astype(float) # converting object columns to floats
```

This will replace all `T` or `TRACE` elements with 1.0.

Output:

```
10  18/05/2016  26.9  40  20.8  34.0  52.2  20.8  46.5  45.0
11  19/05/2016  25.5  32   0.3  41.6  42.0   0.3  56.3  65.2
12  20/05/2016   8.5  29  18.4   9.0  36.0  18.4  28.6  46.0
13  21/05/2016  24.5  18     1   3.5  17.0     1   4.4  40.0
14  22/05/2016   0.6  18     0   6.5  14.0     0   8.6  20.0
15  23/05/2016   3.5   9   0.6   4.3  14.0   0.6   7.0  15.0
16  24/05/2016   3.6  25     1   3.0  12.0     1  14.9   9.0
17  25/05/2016  25.0  21   2.2  25.6  50.0   2.2  25.0   9.0
```

Comment: Congrats me! This is my 1000th answer.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the issue. New rule doesn't allow me to accept the answer within 3 min. Wait.

Comment: I believe the columns that originally contained text values (i.e. 'T' or 'TRACE') will still be of type `object`.  You should probably convert them to floats.

Comment: @Alexander Good idea. Added that in.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) by `dict`:

```
df = df.replace({'T':1.0, 'TRACE':1.0})
```

And then if necessary convert columns to `float`:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Date','another cols dont need convert'])
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(float)
```

---

```
df = df.replace({'T':1.0, 'TRACE':1.0})
cols = df.columns.difference(['Date','a'])
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(float)
print (df)
    a        Date     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
0  10  18/05/2016  26.9  40.0  20.8  34.0  52.2  20.8  46.5  45.0
1  11  19/05/2016  25.5  32.0   0.3  41.6  42.0   0.3  56.3  65.2
2  12  20/05/2016   8.5  29.0  18.4   9.0  36.0  18.4  28.6  46.0
3  13  21/05/2016  24.5  18.0   1.0   3.5  17.0   1.0   4.4  40.0
4  14  22/05/2016   0.6  18.0   0.0   6.5  14.0   0.0   8.6  20.0
5  15  23/05/2016   3.5   9.0   0.6   4.3  14.0   0.6   7.0  15.0
6  16  24/05/2016   3.6  25.0   1.0   3.0  12.0   1.0  14.9   9.0
7  17  25/05/2016  25.0  21.0   2.2  25.6  50.0   2.2  25.0   9.0

print (df.dtypes)
a         int64
Date     object
2       float64
3       float64
4       float64
5       float64
6       float64
7       float64
8       float64
9       float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer from @jezrael, you can replace and convert to floats in a single statement (assumes the first column is `Date` and the remaining are the desired numeric columns):

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].replace({'T':1.0, 'TRACE':1.0}).astype(float)
```